# Xcode not copying resource to octests bundle

Tags: ios, xcode4

WTF?  Xcode 4.6.2 is refusing to copy one of my resource files to the octest bundle.

These line, from the build log, *work*:

```
CpResource AppName/Resources/Domain.sqlite /Users/colin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-WS-dbpjomrlampddifnmkfrqcashprt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/Domain.sqlite
cd "/Users/colin/Documents/work/daring plan/AppName"
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks "/Users/colin/Documents/work/daring plan/AppName/AppName/Resources/Domain.sqlite" /Users/colin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-WS-dbpjomrlampddifnmkfrqcawhprt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app
```

But these lines, from later in the *same build log*, silently result in nothing being copied:

```
CpResource AppName/Resources/Domain.sqlite /Users/colin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-WS-dbpjomrlampddifnmkfrqcashprt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameLogicTests.octest/Domain.sqlite
cd "/Users/colin/Documents/work/daring plan/AppName"
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks "/Users/colin/Documents/work/daring plan/AppName/AppName/Resources/Domain.sqlite" /Users/colin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-WS-dbpjomrlampddifnmkfrqcawhprt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameLogicTests.octest
```

These are both generated by what look to me to be identical Copy Bundle Resources configurations in the App and LogicTests targets.  I've tried deleting and recreating the line for Domain.sqlite in the LogicTests target, but didn't help.

I have tried deleting both the app and octest bundles from Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator, and Xcode goes ahead and recreates them, but with Domain.sqlite missing from the octest bundle.  WTF.

Comment: Really, what the hell, Xcode?  If I manually copy the file I need into the octest bundle, and then build, Xcode deletes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, tracked it down.  Xcode was copying the file just fine, but it was out of sync with my data model (I thought I'd rebuilt it, but been deceived).  And I am using a 3rd-party library called MagicalRecord to manage the core data stack, and apparently in a recent version it added a property called shouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch.  When I look back farther in my build log, there it is:

```
-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(MagicalRecord) MR_addSqliteStoreNamed:withOptions:](0x17e24f0) Removed incompatible model version: Domain.sqlite
```

Moral of the story:  when you're distributing a pre-built sqlite file with your app, you want

```
[MagicalRecord setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:false];
```